# Use multiple but identical aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use two identical aggregate function is SQL Server, where I use `COUNT(A)` with some condition and `COUNT(A)` with another condition.

For example I want to count all students enrolled in the course ABC, and the second count I want to count all students who have grade A and have enrolled in the same course ABC.

But the result of the `COUNT` will be on the same table but on different column, is it possible to do this and how can I implement it. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

And I want the resulting table

[image]

Comment: please provide some sample data with your desired output in tabular format

Comment: Few quick things would be helpful. Firstly, you tagged sql-server in the question but as per your question it is MySQL. They are different Databases, so would suggest to update the tag. Secondly, if you can provide sample input & output datasets, it will help us to provide an answer faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `conditional aggregation`

```
select name, count(*) as all_student,
       count(case when grade='A' then 1 end) as cnt_A,
       count(case when grade='B' then 1 end) as cnt_B
from course_table c inner join student_table s on c.name=s.course
group by name
```

Comment: okay thankyou very much, i've tried it and it work. Thanks @fahmi

Comment: @mtirtapradja, happyy to help you. Please don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer :)